# want to listen a right click, outside of the popup.?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4.5

I have a popup and i want to close it on mouse outside click. so i made a listener of event **`MouseDownOutside`**. but it listen only left click. i also want to close it to a right click but if i make a right click on popup then it should be opened. i searched on google but second time it hasn't any solution. Does anybody know a way to close the popup?

so creation Code of a popup Looks Like

```
var myPopUp:CustomComponentClass = new CustomComponentClass();
PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopUp, Parent, true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(myPopUp);
```

Closing the popup

```
PopUpManager.removePopUp(myPopUp);
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this :

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN,onRightMouseDown);

function onRightMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  var point:Point = popup.globalToLocal(new Point(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY));

  if(!pointInside(popup,point))
  {
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(popup);
  }
}
```

The pointInside function just checks if point is inside the rectangle of the popup.

```
public function pointInside(obj:DisplayObject, point:Point):Boolean
{
    return (point.x >= 0 && point.y >= 0 && point.x <= obj.width && point.y <= obj.height);
}
```

Comment: Added a function that does it, since the point was converted to the local cordinates of the display object just checking against 0,0 and width height shoud do it, alternatively getBounds(stage).contains(x,y) can be used to check if the point is inside too.